# C# Convert Json to object with duplicated property name with different data type

Tags: c#, json

i have a json string with duplicated property name with different data types. if i removed all duplicated other data types, it will work fine.

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "ctr":0,
         "spend":11839.8600,
         "clicks":6402
      },
      {
         "ctr":0,
         "spend":12320.5000,
         "clicks":5789
      },
      {
         "clicks":{
            "value":13156.0,
            "prior_year":0.0,
            "prior_month":14122.0,
            "prior_month_perc":0.0684039087947882736156351792,
            "prior_year_perc":0.0
         }
      }
   ],
   "timing":null,
   "warnings":[

   ],
   "success":true
}
```

here is the my model class

```
  public class MyTestModel
    {
        public int? ctr { get; set; }
        public decimal? spend { get; set; }
        public int? clicks { get; set; }
    }
```

if i removed this snipped json part, program will work.

```
        {
         "clicks":{
            "value":13156.0,
            "prior_year":0.0,
            "prior_month":14122.0,
            "prior_month_perc":0.0684039087947882736156351792,
            "prior_year_perc":0.0
         }
```

are there any method to stop binding unsupported types to model property.

Comment: You'll have to parse it using Newtonsoft.Json library with `JObject`/`JToken` classes and replace the "bad" node with a number. But really you should be asking how to improve your JSON, because that kind of mixed types is not best practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `JsonConverter` to support either/both types in a 'union' class.

```
public partial class ClicksClass
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public long Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("prior_year")]
    public long PriorYear { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("prior_month")]
    public long PriorMonth { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("prior_month_perc")]
    public double PriorMonthPerc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("prior_year_perc")]
    public long PriorYearPerc { get; set; }
}

public partial struct ClicksUnion
{
    public ClicksClass ClicksClass;
    public long? Integer;

    public static implicit operator ClicksUnion(ClicksClass ClicksClass) => new ClicksUnion { ClicksClass = ClicksClass };
    public static implicit operator ClicksUnion(long Integer) => new ClicksUnion { Integer = Integer };
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters =
        {
            ClicksUnionConverter.Singleton,
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}

internal class ClicksUnionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(ClicksUnion) || t == typeof(ClicksUnion?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Integer:
                var integerValue = serializer.Deserialize<long>(reader);
                return new ClicksUnion { Integer = integerValue };
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                var objectValue = serializer.Deserialize<ClicksClass>(reader);
                return new ClicksUnion { ClicksClass = objectValue };
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type ClicksUnion");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = (ClicksUnion)untypedValue;
        if (value.Integer != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Integer.Value);
            return;
        }
        if (value.ClicksClass != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ClicksClass);
            return;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type ClicksUnion");
    }

    public static readonly ClicksUnionConverter Singleton = new ClicksUnionConverter();
}
```

This means that, once parsed, whenever you get to the `ClickUnion` instances, you can check which field is not null, and that is the one you use.  It depends on your usecase of course.

*BTW, I used [this web site](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp) to write the classes from the json*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize your json string.
While doing so, the data type missmatch causes error and you can safely handle this error using `JsonSerializerSettings` as below

```
MyTestModel result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTestModel>("{json string}", 
                                                           new JsonSerializerSettings {
                                                              Error = MethodToHandleError
                                                           });
```

and then define `MethodToHandleError` something like below. This will be called whenever deserialization error occurs:

```
public void MethodToHandleError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
{
    // log error message -> args.ErrorContext.Error.Message
    // you can also write your own logic here
    args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
}
```