# Deserialize numbered items into collection of objects

Tags: c#, json.net

I am not sure how to correctly ask my question.

I'm facing a problem using JSON.net:
The point is, I am receiving this JSON from a webservice. Apparently this thing has never heard of object oriented programming, and my JSON has the following exemplary structure:

> "meta": {
>   **"collection_t1_driver_selected_invoiceaccount": "911156",
>  "collection_t1_scandate": "11 mei 2020",
>
>   "collection_t1_scandate-value": "2020-05-11",**
>   "collection_t2_driver_selected_invoiceaccount": "911156",
>   "collection_t2_scandate": "11 mei 2020",
>   "collection_t2_scandate-value": "2020-05-11",
>   **"collection_t3_driver_selected_invoiceaccount": "911156",
>  "collection_t3_scandate": "11 mei 2020",
>
>   "collection_t3_scandate-value": "2020-05-11"**
>   }

As you can see there are 3 similar blocks. Is there any way to serialize this into a collection of 3 times the same object with 3 fields with JSON.net?

Comment: Please, share the code, what you've tried

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I am a bit familiar with serializing in Json.net. that's about it

Answer (score 0):

Wow, 3 days and I post the same answer on each day: [C# Convert Json to object with duplicated property name with different data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734655/c-sharp-convert-json-to-object-with-duplicated-property-name-with-different-data/61735026#61735026)

Basically you write a specific JsonConvert class that creates a 'union' of all the possible types and then parses the input field and adds the data to one of the union members.